# after adding constant column in Dataframe it overrides previous one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

'tell_skills' is a dictionary which forms dataframe with columns a,b,c. Now I want to add another constant column d with value 'z'. There are two different dataframes with two different values of z which I want to concatenate. The 'final' dataframe is showing last column 'd' as 150 only instead of 150 and 133 divided into equal number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd

tell_skills = {1: ("NY", "LA", "HO"), 2: ("SA","DA", "AS")}
df_company = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tell_skills, orient='index')
df_company.columns = ['a','b','c']
z = 133
df_company['d'] = z
df_comp=df_company
z = 150
df_company['d'] = z
final = pd.concat([df_comp,df_company])
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and clarify what the expected output is.

Comment: `df_comp = df_company` does not copy anything.

Comment: Goyo, I have edited as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
df_comp=df_company
```

it makes `df_comp` a second reference to the original `df_company` so when

```
`df_comp['d'] = z`
```

will essentially set `df_company['d'] = z`, to make a copy of the dataFrame you can use the `copy` module:

```
import copy
df_comp = copy.deepcopy(df_company)
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html for details about `deepcopy()` vs `copy()`

EDIT: as `Jezzamon` has pointed out the `DataFrame` object has a `.copy()` method which would be preferable to use:

```
df_comp = df_company.copy()
```

Comment: pandas has it's own copy method, much better to use that instead http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: after looking at the source code for `copy`, `deepcopy()` first looks for a method called `__deepcopy__`, if pandas implemented it to call it's own `.copy()` the two methods would be identical but oddly pandas does not do this.